Did Mariner 9 have a magnetometer?
While doing research for this question, I found conflicting info on Mariner 9. There are websites that say it included a magnetometer, such as here and here. But NASA's site doesn't list it and wikipedia doesn't either.
Did it actually include a magnetometer?

Compare these two diagrams: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_4#/media/File:Mariner_3_or_4_diagram.jpg and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_9#/media/File:Mariner_8_diagram.jpg The strut for the low gain antenna of Mariner 3/4 is longer and the magnetometer is mounted below the low gain antenna. On the shorter strut of Mariner 8/9 there is no magnetometer. So Mariner 8/9 was designed without a magnetometer.

A NASA press kit from 1971 shows many diagrams of the spacecraft, including the following:

Notably a magnetometer is not included.
Furthermore, the scientific results catalogue (for lack of a better name of it) does not make any mention of magnetic field readings.

WOw, I've never seen that JPL logo before, cool! It's origin, the artist, and when it started and stopped being used would be a great new question tagged with [tag:space-art], [tag:nasa], and [tag:history]

There have been versions of Mariner with a magnetometer (3, 4) and without (8, 9). The press kit is about 8 and 9
